# How to get clean json from wikipedia API

Tags: json, api, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I want to get the result from a wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_2 as JSON.

I tried using their API: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=February_19&prop=text&formatversion=2&format=json

Though it is giving it as Json format. The content is HTML. I want only the content.

I need a way to get clean result.

Comment: What do you mean by "clean"? Plain text? Wikitext? Only HTML without the JSON wrap?

Comment: i mean without html tags and all, i just need the text

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: i am using JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want plain text without markup, you have first to parse the JSON object and then extract the text from the HTML code:

```js
function htmlToText(html) {
   let tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
   tempDiv.innerHTML = html;
   return tempDiv.textContent || tempDiv.innerText || "";
}

const url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=February_19&prop=text&format=json&formatversion=2&origin=*';

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  const html = data['parse']['text'];
  const plainText = htmlToText(html);
  const array = [...plainText.matchAll(/^\d{4} *–.*/gm)].map(x=>x[0]);
  console.log(array);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Update**: I edited the code above according to the comment below. Now the function extracts all the list items putting them into an array.

Comment: Thanks! but i only need some content eg.`1988 – Shawn Matthias, Canadian ice hockey player` and it could be nice if it is giving output ass array

Comment: How can we get the list of all links available in the 'See Also' section?

Comment: @Abhishek You 
should open a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess by *clean* you mean the source [wikitext](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikitext).  In that case you can use the revisions module:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=February_2&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&formatversion=2&format=json

See [API:Get the contents of a page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Get_the_contents_of_a_page) and [API:Revisions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Revisions) for more info.

Comment: clean, i mean i need this content as in the image [ https://imgur.com/a/Wkr1QpK ]